# Creating A Database Snapshot Listener

Tags: node.js, database, express, http, google-cloud-firestore

Forgive me if I'm heading down the wrong path here, if so, would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

I'm curious about building a snapshot listener in Node/Express that returns database updates similar to how the snapshot listener on cloud firestore works.

For example, a front-end client would be able to listen through a single call, then receive updates in real-time without having to make additional calls.

For simplicity's sake, imagine for some reason we wanted to wrap Firestore's snapshot listener in a node/express function, then pass it onto the client and have identical functionality. How would you go about doing this, or am I totally wide of the mark?

Comment: Building your own persistent listener is definitely possible. If Firebase can do it, so can others.  But explaining how to do this is way too broad for covering succinctly here on Stack Overflow. You'll want to break down the problem into simpler steps, and search for existing sources that already cover each of those. For example, [how to keep an open connection from Node.js to a client](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+keep+an+open+connection+from+Node.js+to+a+client) could be once such step.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the pointer. Also looking into web sockets, which could be part of the solution here.

Comment: Web sockets are an option indeed, but not required. Firestore's realtime listeners don't use web sockets for example, but the listeners on Firebase's other database (Realtime Database) do.

Comment: I have posted the comments as community wiki. so that others could spot the workaround easier

Answer (score 0):

Answering this as Community wiki. As mentioned in the comments,

Building your own persistent listener is definitely possible. If Firebase can do it, so can others.

Web sockets are an option indeed, but not required. Firestore's realtime listeners don't use web sockets for example, but the listeners on Firebase's other database (Realtime Database) do.